# How to reuse badly cooked chicken

Tags: chicken

I marinated chicken breast cubes in teriyaki sauce for aboutt 1 hour. I then cooked it together with the sauce it was marinating with for about 15 min on medium heat.

The result was gummy (probably overcooked), hard to swallow chicken that tasted pretty bad.

I don’t want to just throw it out, but I can’t eat it thr way it is either. Is there a way I can treat it (say even in soup) to make it edible?

Answer (score 5):

Finely chopped or even shredded you could add it to fried rice or noodles (you could use a food processor). The other thing that sometimes works with overcooked chicken is to have it cold, sliced fairly thinly in a sandwich or chopped in a salad, but that may be awkward starting from cubes (unless you like it mixed with mayonnaise).

Comment: Chicken salad can work depending on the flavor.  I’d recommend some diced celery to add texture as that sounds to be lacking

Answer (score 2):

The ‘taste[s] pretty bad’ is the only problem part.

The rest is answered by casseroles.  Depending on the initial flavor affects what type ... Texmex, Italian, Latin, pot pie, etc.

As chunks aren’t as versatile, If it’s over cooked, you can shred it while it’s still warm. Just mash it it with potato masher and it will shred up.... you can then let it soak in liquid so it’s not too dry.  (This doesn’t work so well if you let it cool off and try to reheat it).  This can then be used to make enchiladas, tamales, stuffed peppers or similar

Comment: I’ve already put it in the fridge. Should I avoid this in that case?

Comment: @GabrieleCirulli the mashing process he describes doesn't work as well when cooled, that's all. The rest of this answer all still would work. Just cut it smaller with a knife in your case (instead of the potato masher)